# Choosing two people from 2 boys and 2 girls

Tags: combinatorics

> If you have 2 boys and 2 girls, how many ways are there to choose two
>   people?

One possible answers comes from saying that there are two possible genders for the first person and two possible genders for the second, giving $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ ways.

However, this can also be done as $\binom{4}{2}$ giving 6 ways.

Why don't these two answers match?

Comment: It depends on whether you are treating the boys/girls as distinguishable. If they are not distinguishable, then method #1 is correct. If they are distinguishable, method #2 is correct. Based on the wording of the problem, I would guess that boys and girls are not distinguishable. I'm happy to elaborate if this requires more explanation.

Comment: But even in method 1 the four possibilities are BB, BG, GB, GG. However, since we are only *choosing* two of them, order should not matter right. So shouldn't the answer only be 3 in that case (as BG and GB should be counted as the same)?

Comment: It depends on whether you are ordering the two people you select. From the way you phrased your question, I assumed that the pair of people you picked was ordered. You're correct that the answer is $3$ if the people you pick are not ordered.

Comment: If it helps to provide context, here was the original problem: "Out of 2 boys and 2 girls, two students are to be chosen to move to the next round. What is the probability that 2 girls will move to the next round?" So here would the girls be distinguishable or indistinguishable, and would order matter?

Comment: Looks to me like the people are indistinguishable and order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > If you have 2 boys and 2 girls, how many ways are there to choose two people?
>
> One possible answers comes from saying that there are two possible genders for the first person and two possible genders for the second, giving $2\cdot 2=4$ ways.
>
> However, this can also be done as ${4\choose 2}$ giving $6$ ways.
>
> Why don't these two answers match?

The first way merely counts the ways to select the gender of the persons, not their identity.  It's also *wrong*, as there are only 3 ways to do so ${BB}, {BG}, {GG}$.  In addition to this you must *still* select the identity of each selected gender; you neglected this step.  There's one way to select two boys, four ways to select a boy and a girl, and one ways to select two girls; for a total of six ways.

The second method directly counts ways to select the identity of the persons, and correctly disregards the order of selection.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to count the number of ways to have two persons in which $1$ must be a girl and $1$ must be a boy then there are: $2\cdot 2 = 4$ ways.

If we want to count the number of ways to have two persons then we have more possibilities since we could have two boys and two girls. So adding $2$ to the above answer we have: $4 + 2 = 6$ ways.

Comment: Wait.. but doesn't the 4 ways already have a case with 2 boys and 2 girls? The possibilities are BB, BG, GB, GG.